# Pandas to_datetime for two dataframes, want same date format

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create two different dataframes with the same date format in Pandas and the original CSV files have two different date formats.  What do I need to use in the to_datetime function to get these dataframes in the same date format?

```
#DF1 (year, month day, time)

Date                        Event
2017, February 03, 09:30    (United States) Unemployment Rate
2017, February 03, 09:30    (United States) Nonfarm Payrolls
2017, February 03, 11:00    (United States) ISM Non-Manufacturing PMI


#DF2 (day.month.year time)

Local time              Open    High    Low     Close
03.02.2017 08:30:00.000 1.07363 1.0775  1.07134 1.0762
03.02.2017 08:35:00.000 1.07626 1.07669 1.07324 1.07375
03.02.2017 08:40:00.000 1.07372 1.07585 1.0736  1.0758
03.02.2017 08:45:00.000 1.0758  1.07626 1.07481 1.07487
03.02.2017 08:50:00.000 1.07488 1.07519 1.0745  1.07515
03.02.2017 08:55:00.000 1.07518 1.07573 1.07478 1.07562
03.02.2017 09:00:00.000 1.07561 1.07729 1.07559 1.07694
03.02.2017 09:05:00.000 1.07693 1.07784 1.07687 1.07757
03.02.2017 09:10:00.000 1.07756 1.07825 1.07669 1.07688
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the same datetime format, but you don't specify exactly what format you want them in, so let us know that, and I can update this answer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2017, February 03, 09:30','2017, February 03, 09:45']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['03.02.2017 08:30:00.00', '03.02.2017 08:35:00.000']})

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df2['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['dates'])
```

Comment: I think dates in df2 need to be corrected first before conversion else the format in both the dates are not common.

Comment: I ran the exact code above and both were converted to standard pandas datetime format.  At that point, it can be converted to whatever format the OP is looking for.  `pd.__version__ = 0.20.2`

Comment: Yes, dates will be converted by this for sure. But in order to maintain a common format you need to do some tweaking, which yes can be done after steps you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to remove last three 0s from the second dataframe. And then add format of the date you want of any one of the dates you want in your dataframe. Please refer the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2017, February 03, 09:30','2017, February 03, 09:45']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['03.02.2017 08:30:00.000', '03.02.2017 08:35:00.000']})
df2['dates'] = df2['dates'].astype(str).str[:-4].astype(str)
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"])
df2["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["dates"],format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
>>>df
            dates
0 2017-02-03 09:30:00
1 2017-02-03 09:45:00
>>>df2
            dates
0 2017-02-03 08:30:00
1 2017-02-03 08:35:00
```